# Is the missable chest in the Mushroom Castle still in the remake?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

In the original Super Mario RPG on SNES, there is a [missable hidden treasure chest](https://protipoftheday.com/node/493.html) that could only be obtained by jumping on a Toad's head the first time you visit Mushroom Castle. Once you enter the throne room, you would be locked out of obtaining it as the toad would no longer respawn.

Is this missable chest still in the Switch remake?

[image: Missable chest in SNES mario rpg]
<sub>Screenshot from [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Missable_content)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the hidden chest in Mushroom Castle is still present in the remake. However there is now a wandering Toad you can jump on when revisiting the castle, meaning you can reach the chest later if you missed your chance earlier.

[image: Standing by hidden chest with a wandering Toad]